# Update value in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <level>
    <node1 />
    <node2 />
    <node3 />
  </level>
</root>
```

What is the simplest way to insert values in node1, node2, node3 ?

C#, Visual Studio 2005

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of the xml fragment you want modified, and an example of how you want it to look after modification.  It is not clear if you are talking about inserting attribute values or inserting child content or elements.

Comment: i added a xml file but is dissapeared. Is there any restrictions ? Should I use special tags ?

Comment: Just paste the xml in the text of your question and mark it up as code.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(@"
    <root>
        <level>
            <node1 />
            <node2 />
            <node3 />
        </level>
    </root>");
XmlElement node1 = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/level/node1") as XmlElement;
if (node1 != null)
{
    node1.InnerText = "something"; // if you want a text
    node1.SetAttribute("attr", "value"); // if you want an attribute
    node1.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("subnode1")); // if you want a subnode
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```cs
//Here is the variable with which you assign a new value to the attribute
string newValue = string.Empty 
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
    
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Root/Node/Element");
node.Attributes[0].Value = newValue;
    
xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile);
```

Credit goes to Padrino.

[How to change XML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-value-file-using-c)

Comment: This updates an existing attribute value, not 'inserting' as what the OP asked for. Nevertheless the question is not very specific too.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement t = XElement.Load("filePath");
t.Element("level").Element("node1").Value = "";
t.Element("level").Element("node2").Value = "";
t.Element("level").Element("node3").Value = "";
t.Save("filePath");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use AppendChild method to inser a child inside a node.

```
yournode.AppendChild(ChildNode);
```

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx)