# Nuke and update nuspec file

Tags: c#, nuke-build

I generate a Nuget package with NUKE, now I need to set the repository url in the nuspec. But I can't figure out how. Is it possible? Or are there any other libraries that can do this?

Comment: _"NUKE is a VFX node-based compositing package created by The Foundry, used for feature films, television, VR, and commercials."_ ..???

Comment: wrong tag sorry

Comment: Apparently not: https://nuke.build/api/Nuke.Common/Nuke.Common.Tools.NuGet.NuGetTasks.html, https://nuke.build/api/Nuke.Common/Nuke.Common.Tools.NuGet.NuGetPackSettings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at `NuGet.Packaging` and it appears to only have a nuspec reader I was unable to find a writer.

Since NuSpec is just and XML File you can use `XmlDocument` to load and change the value.
An Example of that was answered in this question: [Change xml element values in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342681/change-xml-element-values-in-c-sharp)