# How to replace value of a specific node in an XML string?

Tags: c#, xml

My specific case is that I have an XML result from an ASMX service.
I need to scan this XML string for a specific node and "ToLower()" the value in the node.
I can't access the service to simply change the return at that level.

Comment: OK, and what seems to be the problem with this?

Comment: Can you provide any code samples or xml schema to assist in assisting you. Right now I can only give you general advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help get you started: [How to change XML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-value-file-using-c)

Comment: Thanks Nate, knew there was a simple way to do it. Just loaded the string into an XmlDocument object, got elements by tag name, changed value and rewrote XML to a new string.