# Update the xml database using C#

Tags: c#

I have created a login form and the login details like username and password gets stored in xml database.

Now when a particular user wants to change his/her password. how to do that using xml database in C#. I don't have much idea on xml database. please help me out at the earliest.

Change password form looks like this

```
User name : 
Old password:
new password:
Confirm password:

Change(button)
```

when the user provides the necessary information and clicks the change button. the old password which gets stored in xml database should get replaced by the new password..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "xml database"?

Comment: Do not forget file locking if you implement this in a simultaneous multi-user environment...

Answer (score 0):

See [how to change xml value file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-value-file-using-c-sharp)

and [How To Modify and Save XML with the XmlDocument Class in the .NET Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox_Remember.Checked)
                {
                    UpdateAppSettings_("Remember", "1");
                    UpdateAppSettings_("UserName", User.UserName);
                    UpdateAppSettings_("Password", password);
                }
    }
private void UpdateAppSettings_(string KeyName, string KeyValue)
    {
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
        {
            if (xElement.Name == "appSettings")
            {
                foreach (XmlNode xNode in xElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value == KeyName)
                    {
                        xNode.Attributes[1].Value = KeyValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    }
```