# How to save an integer variable to an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, xna

I know how to read content from an XML file, but I don't know how to write something into it.

For example, I read an integer variable from an XML file and modify it. After modifying, I want to save the integer variable to the same XML file. The old integer value must be replaced with the new value. My game runs on Windows 7.

I load the XML file with this code:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    scorexml = Content.Load<List<Gamescore>>("Score");
    foreach (Gamescore score in scorexml)
    {
        score.Load(Content);
    }   
}  


public class Gamescore
{
    int score;
    public int Score
    {
        get { return score; }
        set { score = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-value-file-using-c-sharp
If it works for you, I will post it as an answer!

Comment: @DanielA.White That's XNA's class for loading game assets.

Comment: In your example you can use auto-properties to save you some typing: `public int Score { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two approaches.

1. Using a class that represent your XML and that implements the [ISerializable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx):

   - deserialize the xml into an object, instance of the class.
   - process the data (setting integer values or whatever).
   - serialize the object into the xml file.
2. Using [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) to process the XML:

   - create a XDocument from xml file.
   - process the XDocument with Linq.
   - save the XDocument into the xml file.

Comment: I tried this tutorial: http://wellroundedgeek.com/post/2011/01/25/Simple-XNA-Cross-Platform-Settings-Manager.aspx

Comment: @Homer_Simpson, I'm not sure the best way to report a broken link so before deleting  it or flagging it (No option in flags say broken) I figured I'd let you know in case you had an updated link.