# Multi line text editing using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to edit a text file using Visual studio VB.net probably its an XML file. I want to edit a particular part of a line for every line in the text file, just like putting value based on input from the text-box. 
I have no idea how to start with this, please suggest how to achieve this. For example here what i am trying to achieve:
In text file Lines:

```
<Variable name = "Mobile" value="">
<Variable name = "Number" value="">
<Variable name = "Server name" value="">
<Variable name = "IP address" value="">
```

Now based on above i want to put in values of the empty "value" field by fetching a value from the VS text-box input.

```
 <Variable name = "Mobile" value="nokia">
    <Variable name = "Number" value="lost">
    <Variable name = "Server name" value="blocked">
    <Variable name = "IP address" value="10.111.121.5">
```

I am totally clueless any Idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to get an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-attribute