# Change xml element outer text c#

Tags: c#, xml, element

Hi I have a xml file that contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <iconback img1="iconback" />
    <iconmask img1="iconmask" />
    <iconupon img1="iconupon" />
    <scale factor="0.7" />
</resources>
```

How can I change and save the `img="iconback"` outer text and `Scale factor="0.7`?

Everything I try fails with

> Cannot set a value on node type 'Element'

Comment: `img1/factor` is called an `attribute`, `iconupon/scale` is called an `element`, so you could search for questions like [how to set xml attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-attribute)

Comment: Got it thanks. Cant believe how easy it was when you know the correct terms thanks.